# Open source project for JavaEE beginner

Tags: java, open-source

Im a junior java ee developer and i want to contribute to the opensource projects. I looked at OpenEJB and Hibernate tasks, and found that they are too difficult for me. For example, at OpenEJB many of tasks are related to bytecode modification, and in hibernate many issues are related to use of dbms specific features or integration issues. What i'm doing wrong? Only experienced programmers are able to contribute to such projects or there is opportunity for begginer?

Comment: This isn't a [good question](http://stackoverflow.com/faq) for Stack Overflow.

Comment: It may be off topic but I believe the downvoters are a bit harsh.  People, please don't blindly downvote.  First try leaving some feedback for the poster to help them avoid making more mistakes.

Comment: Actually, the biggest thing OpenEJB/TomEE needs right now are people to help make videos, flush out documentation, write more examples, help work on the console, fill out the tests, write more validation logic.  Things of that nature.  Most people don't contribute that stuff and only want to do the fancy things.

Comment: @DavidBlevins, thanks for your feedback. I'll try to contribute with tests, examples, and validation. But, can you give me some contact info, except dev mailing list?

Comment: @YegorChumakov Absolutely, dblevins (at) apache.org

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Start out small - don't try to compete with people with years of experience. There are various ways to contribute, including updating documentation, testing installations and reviewing existing documentation to ensure it's still up to date and relevant.

As you work your way through the documentation, you will learn more about the project and will eventually find yourself in a position to make small changes at first, bigger ones later. Just don't give up - you will get there eventually.